# Reference for bijection in distributive lattices

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, lattice-orders

I search a reference (in a book if possible) for the following for finite distributive lattice $L$ with minimum $m$ and maximum $M$. Let $M(L)$ be the set of meet-irreducibles of $L$ and $J(L)$ the set of join-irreducibles of $L$.

Then $\phi: M(L)  \rightarrow J(L) $ given by $\phi(x)=\min ( L \setminus [m,x])$ is a bijection and $x$ is meet-irreducible iff $|\min ( L \setminus [m,x])|=1$

Comment: In *Introduction to Lattices and Order* by Davey and Priestley, 2nd ed., Exercise 5.7 has a content similar to the first sentence above. It is indeed an order-isomorphism (stronger than just a bijection), but in the exercise the map goes in the opposite direction. It is perfectly similar, but you still would have to prove it. Regarding the last statement, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @amrsa Thank you very much! This is very useful, but a reference that states it as a result rather than an exercise would of course be better. Why does my last statement make no sense? In words I say that $x$ is meet-irreducible if and only if the set $\min(L \setminus [m,x] )$ has cardinality one.

Comment: @amrsa I have a proof but I search for a reference to cite it. An exercise is ok to cite (and the books looks like it is a good reference) it but of course it looks usually better when one cites a result in a book rather than an exercise.

Comment: The last statement doesn't make sense because $\min(L\setminus[m,x])$ is an element, not a set. And anyway, $x$ was already taken to be meet-irreducible. Perhaps you mean that $L\setminus[m,x]$ has a minimum iff $x$ is meet-irreducible?

Comment: @amrsa $min(..)$ denotes the set of minimal elements (and is identified with an element in case it has just one element, as is common practise). But yes, your formulation that $L \setminus [m,x]$ has a unique minimum iff x is meet-irreducible also works. (note that the unique minimum in $L \setminus [m,x]$ is in general not the unique element which covers $x$)

Comment: Ok, it was a notational confusion then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the result in the book by Steven Roman on lattices and orders as theorem 4.27.